# react-native - Image require local path from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, image, react-native, require

Hello comunity :) I am working on a testapp in react-native and try to get Images from a local storage place. Actual what i am doing: I give an image directlink source to a var and call this method at my render function.

```
*react: ^0.14.8 ||*
*react-native: ^0.23.1||*
*npm: 2.15.1 ||*
*node: v4.4.4*
```

> Working:

**ImageCall-File (Imagefile.js)**

```
var samplepicture;

setPicture(){
    samplepicture= require('./images/picture.png')
}
render() { 
    this.setPicture; 
    return(
        <Image source=samplepicture/>
    ); 
}
```

*The code snippet above works in a created class wich is named after (Imagefile.js)*

The method above works pretty fine.

Now my where i want to get to > I want to save the image file in a seperated js file wich is styled like a JSON object.

> Not working:

**JS_JSON_File (pictureRef.js)**

```
module.exports = {
    "pictureRef": 
{
    "picture": './images/picture.png'
}}
```

**ImageCall_File (Imagefile.js)**

```
var pictureRef = require('./pictureRef.js');
var samplepicture;

setPicture(){
    samplepicture= require(pictureRef.pictureRef.picture);
}
render() { 
    this.setPicture; 
    return(
        <Image source=samplepicture/>
    ); 
}
```

> Debug the samplepicture:
>   samplepicture = ./images/picture.png

*Not sure if it is relevant but because it is a string it is formatted without the ' '. Also keep in mind that i need to set the image source by the setPicture() function for my code.*

*I debugged both versions of code and had the same output:

- Version 1: samplepicture = ./images/picture.png
- Version 2: samplepicture = ./images/picture.png

*

*Please keep in mind that this is my first question and i really hoped to format everything right. Also i searched for many related issue´s and didnt find any solution*

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems it similar with this [issue1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7015#issuecomment-217390058) [issue2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481)

i think if you use require() to add your image,you should give a static path,not a variable. because they need know the specific image source to bundle.
use json is just like a uncertain source so it doesnt work
now there is a pr to this,

Comment: Thanks for your pretty fast answer. Problematic here in this case to make it static -> In my app i have more than just 1 picture. In my setPicture method i decide wheter the one or other picture is used in a listview. So it would be pretty awesome to make this variable by the json. I will try some solutions written by your linked issue. Maybe i can find a fitted solution for me :)

Comment: I tired everything out. Didn´t find a solution out of those two linked issues. Thanks anyway to you. Maybe it is just not possible at the moment

Comment: for now you can just change you pictureRef code  like ```'picture':require('imagePath')```, then you can use pictureRef.picture to set your image source.

Comment: also in issue2, there comes a PR to solve a variable path to require. but i didnt test now

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a fitting workaround for me :). According to "issue2" this did not work for me either i am to stupid or it just didn´t fit to my problem :) Br

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found today is that no solution for object - variable for dynamically loading from json file in react-native, but have to convert that image to base64 format and add it to json file, after that dispatch it from there by normal.

```js
export class AppModule { }
function _loadDataSoundFromJson(){ 
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
    if (soundData){ 
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        resolve(soundData) },1500) 
    }
 else { 
      reject("No data found") 
    }}); 
};
```

```js
_renderNoPlaying = (item) => {
   return ( 
     <View style={styles.horizontalContainer}> 
     <Image 
        source={{uri : item.img!=null?item.img:nullImg.nil}} 
        resizeMethod={'scale'} 
      style={{
       width:150,
       height:120, 
       borderTopLeftRadius:20,
       borderTopRightRadius:20}}
     /> 
     <Text style={styles.titleItem}>{item.key}</Text> 
)}
```

Comment: function _loadDataSoundFromJson(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if (soundData){
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(soundData)
            },1500) 
            
        }else{
            reject("No data found")
        }
    });
};

Comment: And display: 
_renderNoPlaying=(item)=>{
        return(
                    <View style={styles.horizontalContainer}>
                        <Image source={{uri : item.img!=null?item.img:nullImg.nil}}
                            resizeMethod={'scale'}   
                            style={{width:150,height:120, borderTopLeftRadius:20,borderTopRightRadius:20}}/>
                        <Text style={styles.titleItem}>{item.key}</Text>
                    </View> 
        )
    }