# Require file or image dynamically in require method

Tags: image, dynamic, require, react-native, react-native-listview

I am using reactnative for mobile application and got an issue
    I have json file which i am requiring in js file.
    In json file there is also lots of image path.
    When I am requiring json file from a folder in my js file 
    then path will be changed for that images which is in json file,
    and I am also not able to pass the dynamic string in require method.

Here is my code in JSON file:

```
 {
  "Industry": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "UpperImg": "../../../uploads/bposervices/industry/Bankingimg.png",
      "FiledName": "Financial Services",
      "FileName": "FS.json",
      "Url"       :"uploads/json/FS.json"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "UpperImg": "../../../uploads/bposervices/industry/Insimg.png",
      "FiledName": "Insurance",
      "FileName": "Insurance.json",
      "Url"       :"uploads/json/Insurance.json"
    }
  ],

  "Enterprises": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "UpperImg": "uploads/bposervices/enterprise/Faimg.png",
      "FiledName": "Finance & Accounting",
      "FileName": "FandA.json",
      "Url"       :"uploads/json/FandA.json"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "UpperImg": "uploads/bposervices/enterprise/Spimg.png",
      "FiledName": "Sourcing & Procurement",
      "FileName": "SandP.json",
      "Url"       :"uploads/json/SandP.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my js file:

```
const abc = require('../../folder/a.json)
class B extends component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Content>
          <List
            dataArray={abc.industry} renderRow={dataIndustry =>
              <ListItem>
                <Card>
                  <CardItem cardBody>
                    <Image source={dataIndustry.UpperImg}/>
                   // or <Image source ={require(dataIndustry.UpperImg)/> 
                  </CardItem>
                  <CardItem>
                    <Text>{dataIndustry.FiledName}</Text>
                  </CardItem>
                </Card>
              </ListItem>
            }
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

when I iterate the the array of object of json file, 
I get the image path  which I pass in require method, 
but it is not accepting dynamic image path in require 
method neither in image source.

Can anyone suggest me  how can I get the same?

Comment: This might not be possible @shyam-kumar. See this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608591/react-native-image-require-local-path-from-json)
Also
[this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481)
and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7015#issuecomment-217390058)